# Selecting elements that are not below a given element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm struggling with a css selector. I need a css rule that returns all input fields but those below a specific one.

This is a html code example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <input name="apple">
        <div class="sub">
            <input name="banana">
            <input name="grapefruit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The spoken rule is:

**Give me all input fields below `#container`but not those below an element with the class name "sub".**

The html code is dynamic, so I can't rely on simple child selectors like `>`. I already fiddled around with the `:not()` selector but had no luck so far.

Note: I'm using jQuery for element selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be looking at something like this;

```
$('input:not(.sub input)')
```

The `:not` selector is excluding the input elements which are below sub. You could also use something like this which might be clearer:

```
$('input').not($('.sub').find('*'));
```

Comment: Sometimes the solutions are so simple %-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container input").filter(
                    function (){
                                 return $(this).parent().hasClass("sub")==false
                               }
                            ).css('background-color','red'); //make those elements - RED
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but Matts solution is a more elegant one so I stick to that.